# Finding best fitted value for power function. please help!

Tags: statistics, exponentiation, absolute-value

I need to find:
1. the best fitted value for $a$ in the power function
2. the best fitted value for $b$ in the power function

Data given:
[image]

I know that $b=bi$ and $a=e^{bo}$ --> my question is how to find $bo$ and $bi$, since $log$ equations are given? can I use this equation to find bi for power function:

$Exy- (Ex)(Ey)$
     --------
         $n$

---

$Ex2-(Ex)2$
     -------
        $n$

Where $E$ stands for addition.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So $y = a_0x^{a_1}$ take the logarithm $log(y)=log(a_0)+a_1*log(x)$. This is a linear regression, use the standard formulas.
$y = a*exp(b*x)$ take the logarithm $log(y)=log(a)+b*x$ This is also a simple linear regression, where you can use the standard formulas.

Comment: ok, but how can these equations be used when dealing with this problem? Could you please help??

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression